# Как прочитать в сервисе значение из реестра?

Tags: c#, реестр

Столкнулся с проблемой. Есть WF, в ней есть часть кода по сохранению значения в реестре:

```
using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Test"))
            {
                rk.SetValue("language", path);
            }
```

Аналогично, я считываю значение, на это этапе все гуд:

```
   using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Test"))
    {
        string path = rk.GetValue("language", "").ToString();
    }
```

Но я пытаюсь считать данное значение из написанного мной СЕРВИСА - ничего нет, ничего не считывается. Подскажите, есть ли какие нюансы при чтении реестра из сервиса? Где искать ошибку и в чем она?

Comment: у меня ваш код работает хорошо, еще раз объясните, что не так ?

Comment: значение в реестр записываю из WF, а считываю в сервисе. При таком варианте в сервисе ничего не считывает.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов сервис, имеется ввиду, служба ОС? Она запускается под тем же пользователем?

Comment: да, служба ОС. У вас работает вариант c WF и службой ОС?

Comment: Не пробовал, но очевидно чтобы обращаться к одному и тому же `Registry.CurrentUser` и приложение и служба должны запускаться под одним пользователем, скорее всего у вас не так. P.S. сокращение WF сбивает с толку, пишите Windows Forms или просто приложение.

Comment: Служба запускается с системной учётной записью. Я думал, что играет роль пользователь, под которым я зашел в ОС? Нет.

Comment: В общем, данная ветка недоступна если служба будет запущена под системной учетной записью. Поэтому стоит искать другой вариант.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Registry.CurrentUser`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.currentuser(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает ветку текущего пользователя. Если служба запущена под системной учетной записью, то вернется ветка, соответствующая пользователю System.

В зависимости от ситуации можете попробовать:

1. запускать приложение и службу от одного пользователя;
2. создавать ключ в [`Registry.LocalMachine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.localmachine(v=vs.110).aspx) — возможно потребуются дополнительные разрешения;
3. создавать ключ для пользователя, а в сервисе перебирать ветки пользователей через [`Registry.Users`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.localmachine(v=vs.110).aspx) — возникнут проблемы при параллельной работе пользователя и службы;
4. обмениваться данными не через реестр (файловую систему, базу данных).

Comment: 1 не подходит, т.к. служба может запускаться под любым пользователем со своими правами. 2 Не у всех пользователей может быть доступ к данных ветке 3. При запуске службы блокируется панель настроек в программе, поэтому конфликта не будет При этом с сервиса осуществляется только чтение. . Но пользователи с разными правами и вопрос в доступе. 4 С реестром отпадает вариант однозначно, вижу только вариант использовать config файл в CommonAppData

Comment: @АлександрПузанов Понятно. Подход с общедоступным расположением кажется наиболее простым. В [похожем вопросе на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033987/using-a-windows-application-to-modify-settings-used-by-a-windows-service) рассматривается вариант с переопределением расположения настроек для приложения, что несколько сложнее. Поэкспериментируйте, выберите подходящий вариант.